# How to avoid Y axis negative values from google charts

Tags: php, charts

How to avoid the negative values from google chart, I tried  viewWindow: {                           min: 0,} in my Y axis, but still it showing negative values only.
 please help some one please. Thanks in advance

```
 <div class="timeline-item">
                    <div id="top_x_div" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStacked);

function drawStacked() {
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
           ['Courses', 'Students'],

          ["Electronics",  2 ],
            ]);

        var options = {



    legend: { position: 'none' },
                 isStacked: true,
                   colors: ['green'],

                    bars: 'vertical', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
                    axes: {
                      x: {
                        0: { side: 'bottom', label: 'Percentage'} // Top x-axis.
                      }
                    },

                    axes: {
                      y: {
                        0: { side: 'bottom', label: 'Students'}, // Top x-axis.
                       /* viewWindow: {
                                     min: 0,
                                    },*/
                      }
                    },  
                vAxis: {
                    viewWindow: {
                        min: 0
                    }
                },

                    bar: { groupWidth: "90%" }
                  };
        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
};
</script>
```

Comment: does the data contain negative values? when i draw the chart above, don't see any -- also, there are several options not supported by _material_ charts, see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143) -- recommend using _core_ chart with option for --> `theme: 'material` instead...

Comment: Actually chart data not containing any negative values, But now i think that the negative values comes because when there is no students(zero students) for the particular course @WhiteHat

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the viewWindow on the vAxis option.

```
vAxis: {
    viewWindow: {
        min: 0
    }
}
```

[Source](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options)

Comment: Your code doesn't show that? You've added the viewWindow to the axes object

Comment: still there is no change

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, but I calculated and set vAxis.maxValue, and when it equals 0 (all data are 0) I saw negative scale. If I set maxValue to at least 1 - negative part of scale has gone.